# JavaCV Image blur

Tags: android, javacv

has anyone used `JavaCV` ?

I am trying to achieve a blur around the margins of a custom shaped figure which is actually an image with  transparency around that figure? I keep getting this error each time I use the `blur()` function : `java.lang.RuntimeException: vector::_M_fill_insert`, still I used cvSmooth but it just  blurs the entire image... so is there any way in JavaCV you can add feathering or some kind of blurring around a custom shaped image... it is a pretty huge library with a lot of functions ... so I figured it has to offer something...

I haven't found any kind of documentation for `JavaCV` ...

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a copy of Src Image cvCloneImage()
2. Blur the clone image cvSmooth()
3. Add srcImage to blued Image cvAdd()

Comment: Hello, well I managed to achieve something ...but my idea is to achieve a blur only for the alpha channel (as adding feathering around the countor of the transparent part...) so I did manage to use cvSplit to split my channels and added the smooth for the alpha channel...I did achieve a blur effect around the margins ... but the big problem is that it messes up the margins as well as instead of making only the alpha channel vary it adds a lot blue...red on the margins which makes no sense...because it shouldn't change the color. please let me know if you can help ... I can also provide images.

Comment: @cataHHH I want to add a logo to a IplImage. For this I use cvAdd(_input1, _input2, _result,null). This function litreally adds the two images and gives the resultant color. I simply wish to add an overlay to _input1. Can you please help me. I am using JavaCv and ANdroid.